# VS 2022 loading imports by itself

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

VS 2022 17.9 has a habit of adding imports to WPF apps by itself. I will get an error like '.ToolTip is not a member of Button' - when I go back to the page, I find all sorts of imports have been added, like this:

```
Imports WinRT
Imports Microsoft.Graph.Models
Imports Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports DevComponents.WpfEditors
Imports Microsoft.Graph.Groups.Item.Planner.Plans.Item.Buckets.Item.Tasks.Item.Details
Imports Microsoft.Graph.Groups.Item.Planner.Plans.Item.Details
Imports Microsoft.Graph.Groups.Item.Planner.Plans.Item.Tasks.Item.Details
Imports Microsoft.Graph.Models
Imports Microsoft.Identity.Client.NativeInterop
Imports Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.Provider
```

Is there any way to stop this behaviour?

Comment: This shouldn't be specific to 17.9. Can you check if you have auto-adding of imports enabled?  Options => Text Editor=> Visual Basic => Advanced => Import Directives => Add missing imports on paste.

Comment: The only reason I quoted 17.9 is because it only started to do this after the last update. If you want to add  that as the answer I can mark it up. Thank you. It was driving me nuts!

Comment: Applied that and just edited a page and it's still doing it! Do I need to close VS and reopen it?

Answer (score -1):

You can uncheck Add missing imports on paste.

It is available in Options→Text Editor→ Visual Basic→Advanced→ Import Directives.